# Deserialize to newer version

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, versioning, versions

I have a binary file that was serialized from a class.
That class has been updated.

Now I need to deserialize the old file to the new class.

I don't have access to the old code, but i have access to the old class.

The Class was serialized using BinaryFormatter.

Is there a way to do that?

If not, maybe there a way to deserialize and save only the data that appears in both of the versions?

Comment: What is the question? What happens now? (What exception etc). What were the changes made? Added fields? Removed? Renamed? Subclassed? What? Also: how come you don't have access to the old source?

Comment: Referenced topic talks about the other direction but the resolution is the same.

Comment: On the overall theme of versioned serialization: yes... BinaryFormatter isn't great at that... one of the many reasons tools like protobuf-net exist.

Comment: Agree with Marc - protobuf is the way to go! (+1 on the comment, btw).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the old assembly you can upgrade quite easily by:

- deserialize to objects with old class type
- write a mapper mapping old data fields to the fields in the new class
- serialize the objects of the new class

In the mapper you can convert the old data, add new data etc.

Comment: how to create a mapper?

Comment: The Mapper should be a class which takes an object of the old class and one of the new (or creates a new object then) and copies all values to the corresponding fields from the old to the new.

Comment: i thought about that, but then i realized that there are some private and readonly fields. and some fiels that auto-generated at runtime and needed to be loaded to the new class as well

Comment: Well then it's getting a little bit dirty.
You can use reflection to access the private fields in the old class.
Fields filled at runtime should not be a problem because you actually load the old object.

Comment: #2: Anyway you should think about a datastructure to avoid this slow, errorprone and all in all quite hard to maintain reflection workaround in future releases.